# Iphone syncing via cable

Tags: iphone, usb, synchronization, dock

I've made an IPhone App that communicates to a service by calling a webservice and exchanging data as xml. For this to take place, there should be WIFI access.

What I'm trying to do now is to do the same but in places without WIFI access. The only way I can think of doing this would be through the USB cable (dock cable?). Unfortunately, no amount of searching online has revealed a way to do this. Is it even possible? Does anyone know how to do this? Some pointers on at least where to look for this information would be nice

Comment: It didn't occur to me to mention this before but I need to connect to a Mac (and if possible a PC) and exchange xml information. Also this has to work for both the iphone and ipod so no carrier dependent solutions will work

Comment: Hi fahd ,  i am trying same thing for iPhone iOS 10 , can it possible now ? i found one app iXpand provided by SanDisk which sync videos and photos through Apple lightning cable . any  comment on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syncing through the USB cable is not possible AFAIK. Any syncing you do has to be over the network.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Cultured Code does syncing over Wifi, and on their wiki, [they've found that you can do the same thing over USB and Bluetooth](http://culturedcode.com/things/wiki/index.php/Syncing_between_Mac_and_iPhone_using_USB_or_Bluetooth) (provided the carrier supports tethering, cough cough AT&T cough cough).

So basically, as far as I know, if you do standard Bonjour syncing over a computer-to-computer network, it'll work over USB (and even Bluetooth) if the iPhone has tethering capabilities.

Comment: Carrier? My app is supposed to run on both the iphone and ipod so I'm not sure how that will work. Any comments on this? Also Why would tethering be dependant on the carrier anyway if all I'm doing is transfering data to and from a local computer (which may have its own wired or wifi connection)

Comment: Well, this isn't an official way for syncing over USB -- its a hack that relies on tethering. In some countries, tethering is disabled on the iPhone, so it wouldn't work. On the iPod Touch, its completely impossible. So this type of of USB syncing shouldn't be the primary way of syncing, just an alternative for the lucky people who have tethering enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The cable is simply USB, and you can certainly talk to a computer through this protocol. There is a developer program for this as well.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/accessories/

-t

Comment: I'm slightly confused about this. This program is for having your iphone/ipod talk to an accessory. Would a Mac/Windows machine count as one? Also would you know if enrolling in this program costs anything? I didn't complete the enrollment myself since it needed some company info which I didn't have and my boss would like to know about costs before he goes ahead.