# What are the protocols supported in Iphone's External Accessory Framework

Tags: iphone, usb, ipod-touch, protocols

I'm working on an iphone/ipod app that will need to communicate with a computer (MAC for now, maybe PC if possible) though the USB dock connector cable. I'm a complete beginner with IPhone programming and from what I've been able to find out, the External Accessory framework is the place to start.

While going through the online documentation about the framework I came across references to supported protocols. I couldn't find any more information about them so I'm wondering what they mean by protocols? Are they well known ones like HTTP, FTP etc? or am I completely off the mark?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The External Accessory framework is for communication with custom hardware via the USB dock connector on the iPhone, or through Bluetooth.  The device you are attempting to connect with must be part of the Made for iPod program, and must contain a chip that will decode the communication between the iPhone and the device.

The protocols referred to in the framework documentation are particular to each piece of hardware.  The hardware manufacturer of, say, a game controller could set up a protocol for reading button presses or joystick movement.  Any application which handled this protocol could then use that hardware accessory.

You will not be able to use the External Accessory framework to sync data via the USB connector.  As Gerry suggests, you'll need to use WiFi or some other networking means to do so.  In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061121/iphone-syncing-via-cable), Saurabh Sharan pointed out a [hack for doing this through a tethered USB connection](http://culturedcode.com/things/wiki/index.php/Syncing_between_Mac_and_iPhone_using_USB_or_Bluetooth) that the Cultured Code folks put together.

Comment: Thanks. that really helped clear a lot of things. I wish I could do it the way Saurabh suggested but that is an IPhone specific thing and my app is more for the IPod so I wont be able to use that hack...

cant seem to think of any other way, please let me know if you can

Comment: Other than USB dock, also Bluetooth.

Comment: But it's possible to use the protocol in developer mode without the hardware being registered for that program... right? (E.g. those redpark cables, it's possible to connect with them and I think they are not registered). Related: I have a custom vendor device and am in direct contact with the producer but we still don't know what string to enter as "protocol". Who creates this protocol name, where?

Comment: @Ixx - The Redpark cables are [registered with the MFi program](http://redpark.com/services/enterprise/), which is why they can be accessed using the External Accessory framework. It was my understanding that the protocol string was defined by the hardware manufacturer, but it's been years since I worked in this area.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is for custom devices. For communicating with computers, I would use Wi-Fi.

If you are syncing data with a Mac app, I would check out [ZSync](http://www.zarrastudios.com/ZSync/ZSync.html).