# Where can I get a complete list of Made For iPod devices that use Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, frameworks, external, ios-frameworks, accessory

Am working with a client to interface an iPad with a 3rd party device, a weight scale, that transmits its data via Bluetooth.  I'm not building a an interface FOR the device, just trying to receive data FROM the device over Bluetooth.

The Apple doc indicates I need to use the External Accessory framework to communicate.  You also "must include the UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols key in your application’s Info.plist" and list the specific protocol.

1) Is there a complete list of those protocols and what the format is for the Info.plist somewhere?  The Manufacturer doc indicates it is certified as a Continua member, meaning it uses the ISO/IEEE 11073-104XX Personal Area Network device protocol.  How do I plug that in?

2) Do I really need to use External Accessory framework for an ISO/IEEE standard device?

Comment: Have you found any answer for this. I also need to use standard IEEE 11073-10417 protocol external bluetooth device to communicate with iPhone. Let me know any solution for this.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, unfortunately the External Accessory framework is for communicating with devices that are certified as part of the MFI (Made For iPod/iPhone) program. If your bluetooth scales are not certified by Apple you are SOL.

You can apply to have a device entered into the MFI program here: http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/ - but it's not a trivial enrolment process.

See more information on a similar question here: [What are the protocols supported in Iphone's External Accessory Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083453/what-are-the-protocols-supported-in-iphones-external-accessory-framework)

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected this would be the answer.  Is there any website where someone could see a (current) complete list of all the MFI certified manufacturers?

Comment: Not that I know of - I image some of those certified don't necessarily want to shout about it (for example, I've done work with one MFI member who's a major competitor of Apple in some fields).

Comment: You can get the list of MFi certified manufactures [here](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#5-1). It requires signing an NDA.