# looking for resource to learn "ExternalAccessory" Framework (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, external, accessory

I am looking for some good resources to learn the External Accessory framework, specially the "Bluetooth accessory interfacing". I know there is a [book by Ken Maskrey](http://www.apress.com/9781430229315) for learning the External Accessory framework but this book does not cover the bluetooth communication.

Some blog posts with some sample codes will be greatly appreciated

Thanks Much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you an approved Made for iPhone/iPod program participant? If you're not you'll find it very difficult to get much information. There is no difference between Bluetooth and Dock connection - you cannot communicate with a third party bluetooth accessory that isn't part of the MFI program.

See this question for more details:

[What are the protocols supported in Iphone's External Accessory Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083453/what-are-the-protocols-supported-in-iphones-external-accessory-framework)

Comment: Hello lxt.. Actually I am integrating Blue Bamboo's Card reader in my app. And the reader I am using only support bluetooth are you sure that there is no difference between Dock connection and Bluetooth connection?

Comment: I see that card reader is part of the MFI program - there is no difference from the external accessory framework's perspective between dock and bluetooth connections. However, you must pair with the bluetooth device first via the settings menu. It will then (assuming it's connected and within range) become available for use using the External Accessory Framework. It is up to the hardware manufacturer as to how exactly you can communicate with it, and which protocols are supported.

Comment: Thanks Man! I am reading the book by Ken Maskrey because there is no diff. in the Doc and Bluetooth connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the correct `protocolString` for the Blue Bamboo's Card reader, and register to observe `EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification`, your app should have received the notification if the Card reader has paired with iPhone and passed the identification process. At least, in your iOS Settings > General > About, you will see the connected accessory information.