# Can you obtain WiFi settings from iOS and pass it to a BLE device (similar to Withings)?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, wifi, mfi

The Withings iOS app has the ability to obtain your wifi settings and pass it to the body scale via Classic Bluetooth (see screenshot below). From what I learnt it's a feature only available through the MFi program, which the Withings Scale is.

[image]

---

I'm building an app that talks to external BLE devices. Since MFi is not required for BLE devices, I'm wondering if there's a way to do the same thing with CoreBluetooth or other frameworks?

From [Apple's MFi FAQ page](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#4-2):

> "Accessories which connect to an Apple device using only Bluetooth Low
>   Energy/BTLE/Bluetooth 4.0 or standard Bluetooth profiles supported by
>   iOS are not part of the MFi Program."

---

Related question on ClassicBluetooth / MFi:

[Can you pass WiFi settings from an iOS device to an ExternalAccessory object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821791/can-you-pass-wifi-settings-from-an-ios-device-to-an-externalaccessory-object)

Comment: Hi Joseph, were you able to figure out an answer for this? I'm interested in doing similar things for a BLE device as well.

Comment: No, unfortunately. As far as I know MFi is the only way :(