# iOS passing WIFI settings to Bluetooth (BLE) device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi, iot

based on this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113936/can-you-obtain-wifi-settings-from-ios-and-pass-it-to-a-ble-device-similar-to-wi)

does iOS10 SDK supports passing/sending Wifi setting/credential to a Bluetooth device? "over BLE maybe?"

I'm thinking about creating an app that will pass the current connected Wifi username/password to a Raspberry PI! is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Since every mobile devices from Apple supporting `iOS10`, also support Bluetooth Low Energy, yes, you can send credentials from the phone to a Bluetooth Smart peripheral device, such as a Raspberry Pi equipped with a Bluetooth 4.0 dongle for instance.

> [See the list of devices supporting iOS 10](https://www.cnet.com/news/ios-10-compatibility-these-are-the-iphones-and-ipads-that-will-and-wont-work-with-ios-10/)
>
> [See the list of Apple devices supporting Bluetooth 4.0](http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/973945)

You simply require a custom service and characteristic on the peripheral, on which your iOS device will write the Wi-Fi credentials to store.

You can further add up security by encrypting the Wi-Fi credentials using a pre-shared key (a unique symetric key per users for instance) before sending it to the Raspberry Pi.