# Can I get the WiFi SSID and password on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, wifi

I need to programatically share WiFi credentials via bluetooth with another device. My plan is first to read the credentials and then send them, but I can't find any documentation on how to read both WiFi and password. Other methods of authenticating the other device are welcome

Comment: Is the other bluetooth device and iOS device?

Comment: You can, but only if you're a member of the [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). This is pretty sensitive information, so they're trying to restrict it to trusted devs only. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26414252/3141234

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica it is another device that I'm developing

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Do I need the MFi certificate to publish or can I develop while I get the certificate?

Comment: No clue. You'll have to look into it

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Pastre Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @tunafish24 just posted the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: that is only possible for devices enrolled with Mfi (Made for iPhone). We ended up asking the user to input WiFi credentials in the app and testing those credentials by joining the new Wifi networking and pinging Google. If they're good, we store them on the Keychain and share it with our other device.

I had to ask an Apple Engineer on WWDC Engineering Hours to get this answer, btw :)