# What is needed for my hardware to connect via WAC

Tags: ios, swift, homekit, wac

I am developing a homekit bridge that I would like to connect to WiFi without the user having to enter it's credentials. So after googling and asking another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826498/can-i-get-the-wifi-ssid-and-password-on-ios), I found that I can use the EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser class to share WiFi settings, but I could not find any documentation about what my hardware should implement in order to be picked up by that class. Any direction or suggestion that does not involve EAWiFiUnconfiguredAccessoryBrowser is welcome

Comment: You need to join the mfi program to get details on WAC https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86783

Comment: Thats it! Thanks! if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it xD